# How to add a Grape::API endpoint after one is already present?

Tags: ruby, ruby-grape, grape-api

I'm having a very strange problem using [Grape](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape).
The structure of the project is not the easiest but still quite straightforward and clean, I have inside a Rails app an `app/api` folder with an API class structured more or less like this:

```
class Api < Grape::API
  prefix 'api/v2'
  ...
  mount V2::Controller::User
  ...
end
```

then I have several classes under `app/api/v2/` that do their jobs, divided in controllers, models, services, validators and so on, the usual stuff.
Everything is "mounted" in `config/application.rb` following official Grape documentation (I won't repeat, only thing that changes is the name of the folders.

I must add another endpoint, instead of 'api/v2' I want something like 'api/internal' or whatever name, I then followed the same structure, adding an `app/api/internal_api.rb` class that follows the same structure of the `Api` class, changing the prefix and some other minor stuff, + the endpoints under `app/api/internal`.
I can run `rails c` and do `InternalApi.new`, the result is as expected and the endpoint under `app/api/internal` are clearly loaded.
When running the app unfortunately the new endpoint doesn't exist, and I don't understand why it has this behaviour.

I've checked `ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths` and everything is in order, what else should I check and what can be the cause for this? I've also installed https://github.com/syedmusamah/grape_on_rails_routes and it shows all routes under `app/api/v2` and nothing under `app/api/internal`. Is it possibile one endpoint is shadowing the other?

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment so I am going to take a shot here and tell me if I am wrong and I will delete the answer.

I am assuming the "API" is "app/api/api.rb" (or to that effect) and this is where the "v2" is mounted.

Given your current design I would recommend moving all your `V2` mounts to a new `V2` namespaced API class eg. ("app/api/v2/api.rb")

```
 module V2
   class API < Grape::API
      version 'v2', using: :path
      mount V2::Controller::User
      #....
   end
 end
```

This will then allow you to create another namespace (Internal) "app/api/internal/api.rb"

```
  module Internal
    class API < Grape::API
      # mount Internal::Controller::User
    end
  end
```

Then alter the existing to just mount those:

```
 class Api < Grape::API
   prefix 'api'
   mount V2::API
   mount Internal::API => '/internal'
 end
```

This will avoid the conflicts so that v2 is reachable via "api/v2" and internal is reachable via "api/internal" (you could even take this further and version that if you wanted to)

**TL;DR**( Just My Opinion and experience)

We run a lot of webservices and I would recommend namespacing them inside of modules from the start specifically to avoid these issues. 
Generally our multi version (single responsibility) API directory structures look like this:

```
app
  api 
    api
      common
      v1
        [lots of other files] 
        base.rb
      v2
        [lots of other files] 
        base.rb
      base.rb
```

This will allow you to mount all your endpoints in "api/api/base.rb" like so

```
module API
  class Base < Grape::API
     prefix 'api'
     mount V1::Base
     mount V2::Base
  end
end
```

This way when you need a new structure you build it in its own module and you just mount it in API::Base and avoid any conflicts.